# Fetching an element from a table where all the values generated dynamically

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How can I fetch the value from the table which changes every time?

Table html code:

```
<td style="background-color:#ABCEA1;color:black;" align="center"><b>3491</b></td>
```

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Comment: Your question title is not a question... it's an HTML snippet. Please make it a question and add more details so that we can see what the problem is and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I tried this and was able to find the answer for my question, All we need to do is find the last element of the table, In my case it was 'Total' and I found it using the xpath. After that adjacent to the 'Total' label by using the getText() method I was able to get the dynamically changing values under the table.

Below is my code for getting the same :

total1 =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("id(\'tbl_report\')//tbody//tr[contains(., 'Total')]/td[4]/b")).getText();